# How to preserve updating output in pipe, e.g. when output has `\r`

Tags: shell, pipe, printf

Whenever I pipe some output that is updating (say with `\r`), e.g. to a pager (`less`), or to colourise parts of it, the pipe seems to drop the lines that are updating.  Any idea how to preserve the updating behaviour while do whatever else I want to do?

MWE:

```bash
(
  echo num1;
  for i in {01..99}; do
    printf "num2: %s\r" $i;
    sleep 0.5;
  done
)
```

Normally the above shows:

```
num1
num2: NN
```

where `NN` counts from `01` to `99`.  But if I pipe the above to `less`, I only see the line `num1`, or say I pipe it to `sed` to make all occurences of `num` bold like this:

```bash
(
  ...
) | sed -e "s/num/$(tput bold)&$(tput sgr0)/g"
```

I only see "**num**1", the line with "num2" disappears. How can I keep the second line?

Comment: **`sed` works on LINES** which are defined in Unix as terminated by newline (hex 0A or octal 012), or abnormally by EOF without newline, so your 'progress' never produces a complete line and `sed` won't process or output it; (only) when the loop completes and exits, that closes the input side of the pipe, causing `sed` to see EOF. `less` similarly waits for a complete line, and when the loop completes and exits `less` displays the lot as `num2: 01^Mnum2: 02^M` etc with each `^M` inverted to indicate a control character. **You do get the _line_, you just can't get _parts_ of a line.**

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, that's exactly the behaviour I see! I was hoping there would be a flag/option to treat those lines as raw characters. But now I understand why that isn't possible. Thanks for your response :)